# Long part names in table of contensts: allign to the left

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, parts

In a project working with the document class book, I have very long part titles, which split along two lines in the TOC. I would like them to be alligned to the left, next to "Part X". My parts do not have page numbers in the TOC and I also added black lines around my part titles in the TOC and would like to find a solution to my allignment problem without destroying these two things. A basic working example looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=35mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}

%Black lines around parts in TOC
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\def\contentsname{{C\MakeLowercase{ontents}}}
\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%
{}{\partname~}{}[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very long part title}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{2.2}

\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows:
[image]

Now, I would like that the second line of the part title is alligned to the first line of the title name. What I want is basically something like

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=35mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}

%Black lines around parts in TOC
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\def\contentsname{{C\MakeLowercase{ontents}}}
\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%
{}{\partname~}{}[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part*{This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very long part title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{I\hspace*{0.4cm}This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very\newline\hspace*{1.5cm}long part title}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{2.2}

\end{document}
```

which leads to the result
[image]

however, in a more automatic way, without doing everything by hand via \newline and \hspace*.